# To get a recursive relation for this type of problem

Tags: combinatorics

Twelve square sheets are placed in a row, and each can be painted with one of the four colors Y,R,O,B. Find the number of ways this can be done so that each block of five adjacent sheets contains at least one sheet of each color . What i tried is that for lower cases of sheets i tried to see the pattern so as to motivate for a recursive relation but going from 7 to 8 case and higher ones needed a recursive relation which i am not able to generate . As lower cases (<8) dont need any recursion it can be easily solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n  \geqslant  5$ be the number of colored sheets, numbered from $1$ to $n$. We extend the system by adding a new sheet in position $0$ and shifting the sheets to the right.

For any coloring $c$, let the repetition index $r \in  \left\{2 , 3 , 4 , 5\right\}$ be
the index of the first sheet with a repeated color. If $r = 5$, it means that the $4$ first sheets have different colors. One can add a new sheet of any of the four colors, it gives $4$ ways to extend the coloring, which respective repetition indexes are $2 , 3 , 4 , 5$.

If $r < 5$, it means that there are only $3$ colors among the
$4$ first sheets and the only way to extend the system is to add a new
sheet which color is the missing color among the $3$. The result is
a coloring which repetition index is $r+1$.

Let ${X}^{\left(n\right)} = {\left({X}_{2}^{\left(n\right)} , {X}_{3}^{\left(n\right)} , {X}_{4}^{\left(n\right)} , {X}_{5}^{\left(n\right)}\right)}^{T}$
be the numbers of coloring with repetition indexes $\left(2 , 3 , 4 , 5\right)$ for
$n$ sheets. The previous reasoning shows that

\begin{equation}
{X}^{\left(n+1\right)} = A {X}^{\left(n\right)} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1
\end{array}\right] {X}^{\left(n\right)}
\end{equation}

In particular, the number ${C}_{n}$ of colorings of $n$ sheets is
${C}_{n} = U {X}^{\left(n\right)}$ where $U = \left(1 , 1 , 1 , 1\right)$. It follows that

\begin{equation}
{C}_{n+k} = U {A}^{k} {X}^{\left(n\right)}
\end{equation}

We claim that $U {A}^{k} = \left({u}_{k-3} , {u}_{k-2} , {u}_{k-1} , {u}_{k}\right)$ where the real sequence ${u}_{k}$ satisfies the recurrence relation

\begin{equation}
\boxed{{u}_{k+1} = {u}_{k}+{u}_{k-1}+{u}_{k-2}+{u}_{k-3}}
\end{equation}

Indeed, this is an immediate consequence of the relation
$U {A}^{k+1} = U {A}^{k} A$. The initial values of $u$ are

\begin{equation}
{u}_{{-3}} = {u}_{{-2}} = {u}_{{-1}} = {u}_{0} = 1
\end{equation}

It follows that

\begin{equation}
{C}_{n+k} = {u}_{k-3} {X}_{2}^{\left(n\right)}+{u}_{k-2} {X}_{3}^{\left(n\right)}+{u}_{k-1} {X}_{4}^{\left(n\right)}+{u}_{k} {X}_{5}^{\left(n\right)}
\end{equation}

For $n = 5$, one has ${X}^{\left(5\right)} = 4 ! \left(1 , 2 , 3 , 4\right)$, hence the formula

\begin{equation}
\boxed{{C}_{5+k} = {24}\times{\left(4 {u}_{k}+3 {u}_{k-1}+2 {u}_{k-2}+{u}_{k-3}\right)}}
\end{equation}

In particular ${C}_{12} = {24}\times{1129} = 27096$

Remark: note that $A$ has the form of a [Companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)

Comment: thx for your method , your method by matrix is kinda new to me but still i like it , its usefulness is seen in the problem . But if someone wanted a recursive way by generating some recurrence relations and finally arriving at expression which can be solved just by putting the previous results of n = 5,6,7,8 to get the 9th similarily others. Thats what i was asking but this is a cool approach so def upvote it ,but as i am not having 15+ points so upvoting is not happening rn but whenever i get it i will do it for sure . If u have a recursive way can u share that if possible ?

Comment: Thx just i meant avoiding the matrices , and getting a recurrence which i was asking for :)

Comment: Wow nice , how u arrived in that recurrence relation?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how the recurrence relation can be obtained. There are still matrices in the proof but you can use the relation without knowing anything about matrices.

Comment: Nice just one thing more what is "uk" i mean the definition for it . As i know Cn definition is total ways for n sheets , so likewise this what is for uk?

Comment: It is only the name that I found for the components of the vector $U A^k$. The nice thing is that these components satisfy a simple recurrence relation. That's where we are lucky.

Comment: Aa i see , nice thx for helping @Gribouillis